# Configure clients to navigate through specific wan. Pfsense

Tags: firewall, nat, pfsense, gateway, outboundrules

I have a machine with a pfsense running. It is configured with three ethernet cards.

LAN 192.168.2.1/21
WAN1 200.41.X.2/24
WAN2 200.41.X.3/24
ISP Gateway 200.41.X.1

This is a connection with 5 different IP addresses.

WAN1 and WAN2 are directly connected to my ISP router.

I need a way to configure some clients navigating through WAN1 and some through WAN2. I am new to pfsense so, please, if you can send me some examples to do this. I can add two squids if it is necessary.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple: just create a firewall rule on your LAN interface that matches the traffic desired (by client IP, perhaps), and then expand the "Gateway" section of "Advanced Features" at the bottom of the rule creation page and select your desired gateway for that traffic.

This technique is called "policy routing", and is present not only on pfsense, but nearly all other routing platforms as well.

Comment: I tried to do as you said, but I have only one Gateway from my ISP Router. Maybe I'm missing some configuration.

Comment: If that's the case, you don't have two internet connections set up, or at least not set up correctly.

Comment: Ok, here's the configuration I have:

Comment: Please don't attempt to put configuration in comments. Edit your question and add the details there.

Comment: Changed configuration